# Upgraded to php 5.3.10 and simpleXMLelement is broken

Tags: simplexml, php

This code was working and when we upgraded to php 5.3.10 it stopped working and started throwing some really odd errors.

The original XML validates on w3c.org without errors however I've edited out the site specific for brevity and security.

The XML (edited for brevity but error is produced on line 1):

```
<AmberAlertDirective  
xmlns="http://www.hidden.com/AmberAlert"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hidden.com/en_US/AmberAlert.xsd">
  <Directive>New</Directive>
  <AmberAlertId>9969</AmberAlertId>
  <MessageTimestamp>2012-03-27T00:35:11</MessageTimestamp>
  <AmberAlert>
    <Target>
      <State Code="OH">
      </State>
    </Target>
  </AmberAlert>
</AmberAlertDirective>
```

The php errors from error_log:

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : AttValue: &quot; or ' expected in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: xmlns=\&quot;http://www.missingkids.com/amber/NCMECAmberAlert\&quot;   in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:       ^ in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : attributes construct error in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: xmlns=\&quot;http://www.missingkids.com/amber/NCMECAmberAlert\&quot;   in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:       ^ in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag AmberAlertDirective line 1 in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: xmlns=\&quot;http://www.missingkids.com/amber/NCMECAmberAlert\&quot;   in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:       ^ in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: xmlns=\&quot;http://www.missingkids.com/amber/NCMECAmberAlert\&quot;   in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:       ^ in /aa.php on line 125
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /aa.php:125
Stack trace:
#0 /aa.php(125): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<AmberAlertDire...')
#1 /AAServlet.php(64): processAmber('<AmberAlertDire...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /aa.php on line 125
```

Comment: And, in case anyone is at work, the URL in the XML is probably nsfw.

Comment: Maybe try example 1 from http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php to see if the xml parsing error is more descript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [turning Off magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) or putting your XML content through [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) before passing to SimpleXML.

Comment: That was exactly the problem!  Spent 8 hours on this one!

Answer (score 1):

From your errors I believe your problem is in not registering your namespaces. Namely your default namespace. There are a few ways of going about it, it just depends on how you are processing the data.

XPATH:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', 'http://www.hidden.com/AmberAlert');
```

children():

```
$xml->children('http://www.hidden.com/AmberAlert');
```